# Expectation of $\ell_\infty$ norm of random vector

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

This is going to be an extremely trivial question but here I go:

$\vec{x}$  is a random vector in $R^n$ where each coordinate is iid, with values -2, -1, 0, 1, 2 with equal probability. How do I compute $\mathbb{E}[||\vec{x}||_\infty]$?

The way I tried to approach this: I know that the $\ell_{\infty}$ norm is $\max |x_i|$, So I am looking for $\mathbb{E}[\max |x_i|]$. For $\max |x_i|$ to be 0, I need all of the $n$ elements of the vector to be zero. I considered that possibility to be $\frac{1}{5^n}$. For $\max |x_i|$ to be 1, I need all elements to be either -1, 1 or 0, so no 2 or -2s. I considered it to be $(1 - \frac{2}{5})^n = (\frac{3}{5})^n$. For $\max |x_i|$ to be 2, I need at least one 2 or -2 of all $n$ elements. I thought this possibility to be $ 1 - (\frac{3}{5})^n$ (since it is the inverse of the second condition.) Then $\mathbb{E}[\max |x_i|] = (1 - \frac{3}{5}^n) 2 + \frac{3}{5}^n 1 + \frac{1}{5}^n 0 = 2 - (\frac{3}{5})^n$. But I don't know if this is right at all. For instance, I called the possibility of having at least 1 2 or -2 to be $ 1 - (\frac{3}{5})^n$, since it is the inverse of the second condition, but when I think about calculating it myself, it also makes sense that it could simply be $\frac{2}{5}$ since I need one of the elements to be 2 or -2 (with possibility $\frac{2}{5}$) and all the other elements could be anything. Could you please help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be more convenient to work out $P(\|X\|_\infty\leq k)$ for each $k\in\{0,1,2\}$ and then write $P(\|X\|_\infty = k) = P(\|X\|_\infty\leq k) - P(\|X\|_\infty\leq k-1)$ for $k\in \{1,2\}$.

$$P(\|X\|_\infty\leq k) = P(|X_1|\leq k)^n = \begin{cases} 
\frac 1{5^n} &\text{if } k=0\\
\frac {3^n}{5^n} &\text{if } k=1\\
1 &\text{if } k=2
\end{cases}$$

Hence $P(\|X\|_\infty = k)=\begin{cases} 
\frac 1{5^n} &\text{if } k=0\\
\frac {3^n-1}{5^n} &\text{if } k=1\\
\frac {5^n-3^n}{5^n} &\text{if } k=2
\end{cases}$ and $$E(\|X\|_\infty) = \frac {3^n-1}{5^n} + 2\frac {5^n-3^n}{5^n}  =
\frac {2\cdot5^n-3^n-1}{5^n} $$

Comment: Alternatively, $$E(||X||_\infty)=\sum_{k\ge 0} P(||X||_\infty > k)=\left(1-\frac{1}{5^n}\right)+\left(1-\frac{3^n}{5^n}\right)=\frac{2\cdot 5^n-3^n-1}{5^n}$$